# Why local browser won't show anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have start learning with reactjs and purely new.i have created a new app in react and wrote the following code in Blog.js:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

const blogBody=()=>{
    return(

          <div class="card">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <h5>Written By Ali</h5>
            <p>Some text..</p>
          </div>

    )

}
class Blog extends Component {

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <blogBody/>
            </div>

         );
    }
}



export default Blog;
```

and my App.js is:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Blog from './Blog'



class App extends Component {
    render() { 
        return (  
            <div className="container">
                <Blog/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App ;
```

when i execute npm start, it shows nothing. then when i go to developer tools it is saying under the  tab

**You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.**

did i do anything wrong with my code or in any setting? but when i run he initial page after creating new app fresh, it is showing the react thing with enable src regular stuff.

where did i do wrong?

this is my first post....please let me know if i break any rules and please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component names have to start with capital letters.

Since `blogBody` doesn't, it is treated as an unknown HTML element and just inserted into the DOM.